# Преобразование типов. Golang

Tags: golang, byte

Я хочу преобразовать byte в int, но не привычным способом.
Если использовать функцию int

```
int(0x30)
```

Мы получим результат 48.
Мне нужно получить 30. Ввели 0x10 получили 10. Ввели 0x11 получили 11 и т.д. Как это сделать?

Comment: а из `0x1a` что должно получиться?

Comment: такое значение в моем случае невозможно. У меня есть датчик и он выплёвывает показатели в таком виде: []byte{0x10, 0x30, 0x00} и они значат 10 30 и 00. Они как-бы сразу в десятичном виде, но передаются в шестнадцатиричном

Comment: ну так составьте словарик, в котором и запишите все нужные вам сопоставления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл подходящее решение:

```
strconv.ParseFloat(strconv.FormatInt(int64(0x30), 16), 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если высчитывать на ходу, то можно попробовать так:

- Получить `hex` как строку
- Перевести строку `hex` как число

Пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    bytes := []byte{0x10, 0x30, 0x00}
    fmt.Println(bytes)
    // [16 48 0]

    numbers := make([]int, len(bytes))
    for i := 0; i < len(bytes); i++ {
        hex_str := fmt.Sprintf("%X", bytes[i])
        num, _ := strconv.Atoi(hex_str)
        numbers[i] = num
    }
    fmt.Println(numbers)
    // [10 30 0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int hex = int(0x30)
int d1 = hex / 16
int d2 = hex % 16
if d1 > 9 || d2 > 9 {
  // panic
  ... 
}
int decimal = d1*10 + d2
```